# Why does sizeof operator fail to work inside function template?

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

I am trying to learn C++ function templates.I am passing an array as pointer to my function template. In that, I am trying to find the size of an array. Here is the function template that I use.

```
template<typename T>
T* average( T *arr)
{
    T *ansPtr,ans,sum = 0.0;    

    size_t sz = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout<<"\nSz is "<<sz<<endl;

    for(int i = 0;i < sz; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    ans = (sum/sz);
    ansPtr = &ans;
    return ansPtr;
}
```

The `cout` statement displays the size of `arr` as `1` even when I am passing the pointer to an array of `5` integers. Now I know this might be a possible duplicate of questions to which I referred earlier but I need a better explanation on this.

Only thing I could come up with is that since templates are invoked at runtime,and `sizeof` is a compile time operator, compiler just ignores the line

```
   int sz = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

since it does not know the exact type of arr until it actually invokes the function.
Is it correct or am I missing something over here? Also is it reliable to send pointer to an array to the function templates?

Comment: This has nothing to do with function templates, you'll get the same thing with a plain function that takes a pointer. A pointer isn't an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: "templates are invoked at runtime" Wait, **what ?!**

Comment: I really need to take compilers class now...

Comment: @abhinole: not really compilers class, just get a good mental picture of the C++ compilation/runtime model. It's a complicated one so nothing to be ashamed of.

Comment: I should correct myself. From wikipedia Templates page....
Templates are considered type-safe; that is, they require type-checking at compile time. Hence, the compiler can determine at compile time whether the type associated with a template definition can perform all of the functions required by that template definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 T *arr
```

This is C++ for "`arr`  is a pointer to `T`". `sizeof(arr)` obviously means "size of the pointer `arr`", not "size of the array `arr`", for obvious reasons. That's the crucial flaw in that plan.

To get the size of an array, the function needs to operate on arrays, obviously not on pointers. As everyone knows (right?) arrays are not pointers.

Furthermore, an average function should return an average value. But `T*` is a "pointer to `T`". An average function should not return a pointer to a value. That is not a value.

Having a pointer return type is not the last offense: returning a pointer to a local variable *is the worst of all*. [Why would you want to steal hotel room keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)

```
template<typename T, std::size_t sz>
T average( T(&arr)[sz])
{
    T ans,sum = 0.0;    

    cout<<"\nSz is "<<sz<<endl;

    for(int i = 0;i < sz; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    ans = (sum/sz);
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I should have mentioned that I wanted to return pointer/reference of average value.But it seems that its not recommended. Further while passing an array, should I use
T average(T arr[])
so that I can find the size inside of template function?

Comment: @abhinole ` T average(T arr[])` and ` T average(T* arr)` are exactly the same to the compiler.

Comment: @abhinole Why do you want to return a pointer or reference to the average value? *The average value doesn't exist beforehand*. It's created in this function. Returning a pointer to it is not going to work well. Returning it by value is the best option.

Comment: Ohh.I understand now.It will go out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to access the size of a passed parameter, you'd have to make that a template parameter, too:

```
template<typename T, size_t Len>
T average(const T (&arr)[Len])
{
    T sum = T();
    cout<<"\nSz is "<<Len<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i < Len; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    return (sum/Len);
}
```

You can then omit the sizeof, obviously. And you cannot accidentially pas a dynamically allocated array, which is a good thing. On the downside, the template will get instantiated not only once for every type, but once for every size. If you want to avoid duplicating the bulk of the code, you could use a second templated function which accepts pointer and length and returns the average. That could get called from an inline function.

```
template<typename T>
T average(const T* arr, size_t len)
{
    T sum = T();
    cout<<"\nSz is "<<len<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i < len; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    return (sum/len);
}

template<typename T, size_t Len>
inline T average(const T (&arr)[Len])
{
    return average(arr, Len);
}
```

Also note that returning the address of a variable which is local to the function is a *very* bad idea, as it will not outlive the function. So better to return a value and let the compiler take care of optimizing away unneccessary copying.

Comment: For most types that you're going to be averaging, the copy will be cheaper than using a pointer.

Comment: You could also use `accumulate(arr, arr+len, T())/len` as the implementation of the average function. See the [docs of `accumulate`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html).

Answer (score 3):

Arrays decay to pointers when passed as a parameter, so you're effectively getting the size of the pointer. It has nothing to do with templates, it's how the language is designed.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the immediate errors, but IMHO, there are two
important points that they haven't addresses.  Both of which I would
consider errors if they occurred in production code:

First, why aren't you using `std::vector`?  For historical reasons, C
style arrays are broken, and generally should be avoided.  There are
exceptions, but they mostly involve static initialization of static
variables.  You should *never* pass C style arrays as a function
argument, because they create the sort of problems you have encountered.
(It's possible to write functions which can deal with both C style 
arrays *and* `std::vector` efficiently.  The function should be a
function template, however, which takes two iterators of the template
type.)

The second is why aren't you using the functions in the standard
library?  Your function can be written in basically one line:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
typename ForwardIterator::value_type
average( ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end )
{
    return std::accumulate( begin, end, 
                            typename::ForwardIterator::value_type() )
                / std::distance( begin, end );
}
```

(This function, of course, isn't reliable for floating point types,
where rounding errors can make the results worthless.  Floating point
raises a whole set of additional issues.  And it probably isn't really
reliable for the integral types either, because of the risk of overflow.
But these are more advanced issues.)